# Does Windows 7 require that a graphics card driver be installed before it can detect the graphics card?

Tags: windows-7

Does Windows 7 require that a graphics card driver be installed before it can detect the graphics card? It seems to me that Windows 7 should be able to detect the existence of the card without the driver being installed. If the card is not detected, it does not show up in the Device Manager. That eliminates that method of installing a driver. I would welcome some insightful comments that specifically answer the question. Thanks.

P.S. My problem has to do with Windows 7 not detecting the card.

Comment: All Windows 7 should do is detect a driver is missing for a device.

Answer (score 4):

Normally a card should at least show up as a Generic VGA device. Also, the card should function and show BIOS POST messages, as well as chunky VGA graphics in Windows.

If you're not getting output, I'd suspect a bad card, or some other hardware issues (some high end GPUs need a power cable).
If you're getting output at the BIOS level but Windows doesn't recognize the card, you might have other issues such as missing chipset (northbridge/southbridge) drivers.

Comment: +1. Last time I installed Windows with an unknown graphics card, I ended up with 16 colour 800x600. Looked terrible but did the job until I installed the driver. These days I think it's pretty rare to not have something better than that available.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the card is seated properly in whichever slot on your motherboard (PCI-E?), and if possible try another slot. Again, if possible - try the card in another machine to determine where the issue lies.

Presumably the fan is spinning on the heatsink?

Comment: I need to correct original question. Windows 7 is detecting the card as VGA only. I installed windows 7. Previously had windows XP. The card worked great with with XP--dual monitors, games,etc. I can safely conclude the card is ok. The VGA portion of the card works fine. DVI is not recognized for other monitor.

Comment: So the graphics card has a VGA and a DVI port, but the monitor on the DVI port isn't getting any signal? 

Are you using the latest drivers from the manufacturers website?

Comment: after much searching, apparently no Windows 7 driver--I ran Windows Upgade Advisor which said card was "compatible". I guess "compatible" does not mean a driver is available. It looks as if I am out of luck. I will re-install XP. Thanks for pointing me is the right direction!!

Comment: If you can find a Vista, Win8, or Server 2008+ driver of the proper bitness you can probably use it. They're almost entirely compatible.